# Mysql: Deleting all rows older than 5 year in every 10 seconds

Tags: mysql

I want to delete the rows older than 5 year in mysql table(item).

```
item
----------------
id       neme         date_and_time
1          a          2015-04-11 11:10:04
2          b          2005-05-22 11:10:04
3          c          2007-06-21 11:10:04
```

How can i doing this delete action?

Also I want to run this delete action in every 10 seconds, I can do this using event scheduler and trigger? What is the different for this two function?

Comment: Every ten seconds is a very frequent interval at which to delete ancient rows. Such a schedule may generate a large amount of overhead in your system for a marginally useful gain.   Many developers of long-lived systems do this kind of cleanup once a day or once a week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create an event like this:

```
CREATE EVENT DO_DELETE_OP
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 10 SECOND
DO DELETE FROM item WHERE date_and_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MONTH);
```

Comment: How to create a cron job in mysql?

Comment: you don't - you create it in linux server o/s

Comment: @paul0080:- Updated the answer with the Events option. Hope that helps!

Comment: your event will only delete it once, 10 seconds in the future, not every 10 seconds.

Comment: I using Windows server to set up mysql , set cron job in Windows?

Comment: @paul0080 no need for cron. it's baked into mysql.

Comment: @paul0080:- Agree with pala, you can simply create an event. Will work for sure!

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi I got it.Thank you for your solution.

Comment: @paul0080:- Yes, you can add insert/ update as well!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mysql scheduler.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html.

Something like:

```
CREATE EVENT cleanup
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 10 SECOND
    DO
      DELETE FROM item WHERE date_and_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 YEAR;
```

In order for this to work, you will need to enable the mysql scheduler, which can be done like this:

`SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`